# Data on unmounted partition keeps changing

Tags: partition, usb-drive, disk-image

I am experiencing a weird issue here. I have a partition on a USB stick that I back up from time to time by creating a simple image like so: `pv -tpreb /dev/sdx1 > /path/to/image_file`. Of course the partition is not mounted while the image is being created.

Recently, by accident, I found out that the data on the partition keeps changing even if it hasn't been mounted since the last backup. To verify, I ran `md5sum /dev/sdx1` multiple times in quick succession and I get a different hash every time. How can this be?? Maybe the USB stick is broken? Any other ideas how this could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make an exact copy using dd and then compare it a few times using cmp.

cmp will stop at the first different byte and tell you the location.

- If that location remains the same each time, you might have a specific bit flipping.
- If it's very early on I would expect that it's caused by Linux making a change to the partition table, etc. even though it shouldn't if it's not being mounted. You could test this further by using dd and cmp on the partition instead of the while device.
- If it's all over the place then something else is probably wrong.

Although in my experience flipping usually happens differently (once flipped, it won't just flip back by itself)

I would also run a tool like https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to test the USB stick before condemning it, but that would be destructive to the data.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with dd and cmp. The partition is 512 MiB in size. The first difference seems to be around byte 477102081 plus minus a couple of bytes. I created a few images with dd and ran `xxd -s 477102083 -l 512 image` on them. The entire output changes completely every time. Looks random to me. The file system on the partition is ext4 btw. fsck returns no error.

Comment: You could try the F3 tool I recommended earlier, it will write a pattern to the drive and then verify the data. I'm not sure how the drive could change even though it's not being mounted, but F3 should be able to confirm if the drive is healthy or bad.

Comment: I tried the F3 tool. At first, it didn't find any errors and even made the problem go away. Probably due to wear-leveling. But after writing some more data, I started getting IO errors. So I conclude the USB stick is a goner.